# Save T-SNE results for future use

Tags: python, gensim, dimensionality-reduction, saving-data

What is the appropriate way to save a `gensim` doc2vec model that has been transformed by T-SNE (from `sklearn.manifold`), e.g.

```
x_full = model[doc_tags]
pca_full = PCA(n_components=50)
pca_result_full = pca_full.fit_transform(x_full)
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, verbose=1)
x_tsne_full = tsne.fit_transform(pca_result_full)
```

where `doc_tags` is the tagged documents that the model was trained on. Reducing this model using T-SNE takes hours, so it would be good to save this for future use.

I have been putting it in a pandas dataframe, such as `df = pd.DataFrame(x_tsne_full, index=doc_tags, columns=['x', 'y'])` then saving this dataframe to CSV for future use. Is this the best way, or is there a T-SNE-appropriate way to save that is not apparent in its docs?

Comment: Why put it in a pandas dataframe? saving the numpy array directly takes a step away, and there are plenty of efficient ways to save an np.array

Comment: I have never used this package but my guess is that since everything in Python is an object, the best way to save tsne results might the same as saving any Python object. May be you can try [pickle](https://www.thoughtco.com/using-pickle-to-save-objects-2813661) package? This is what I would try if I face the same problem, but don't hesitate to let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm new to numpy, thank you! Just saved it using `np.save('tsne.npy', x_tsne_full)` and tested loading it using `np.load('tsne.npy')` and it works perfectly.